# Android: How do you make the image fit in the circle

Tags: android, android-studio, android-xml, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

This is the code I have

```
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_photo"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="120dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
            android:background="@drawable/profile_circular_border_imageview"
            android:elevation="5dp"
            android:padding="20dp"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:src="@drawable/lol"
            tools:scaleType="fitEnd" />
```

How do you make the image fit in the center by not stretching it. Currently, it looks like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdz6U.png

Answer (score 2):

change to,

```
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/user_profile_photo"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/header_cover_image"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="-60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/profile_circular_border_imageview"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/lol" />
```

change the scaleType to

```
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
```

or

```
    android:scaleType="centerInside"
```

Comment: How come it's still the same

Comment: your image is a square image.and the imageView also square.120dp X 120dp. Then how the image getting stretched.